# How to get the entity that field belongs to in the case of an entity reference field

Tags: 8, entities

Here is my use case:

I have created a media bundle (FILM IMG) to store a [media entity (image)](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) field. I can manage it at `admin/structure/media/manage/film_img/fields`

In a content type named "FILM" , I have added a entity reference field which reference my "FILM IMG" media entity bundle.

I am also using [file_field_path](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module to rename the uploaded images.
When I am adding a new image for a new Film, I would like to use hook_filefield_paths_process_file to rename my image file name.

This hook is providing me the media entity ($entity) as a parameter, but of course it is not providing the Film entity that I need (I need it to get some info to rename my file name)

Here is my question: How to get the "parent" entity from the referenced entity;

In other words, with my use case: How to get my film node from the image media entity provided by the hook.

Answer (score 3):

You can get that with an entity query:

```
// Get IDs of all film nodes that reference this entity
$nids = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'film')
  ->condition('field_foo.target_id', $entity->id())
  ->execute();

// Load the nodes
$nodes = Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple($nids);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help, unfortunately, this is not working. Even if I add the missing 'node' parameter :  Drupal::entityQuery('node')..., the result will be empty because I think that the entity is not yet saved when the hook is called. If I run this query after the save operation, I got the expected result.